# add filter on the head of the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have html/php table that display data from database what i need is add filter to sort the data on the head of the table

[image]

please tell me how to add filter to sort data inside the column. here is my code:

```html
<?php include_once 'includes/connection.php'; ?>
<h2>Facebook Forms</h2>
<hr><br>



<table border="4">
    <tr>


         <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">created time</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">specialist</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">full name</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">city</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">country</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">date of birht</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">phone number</td>
        <td bgcolor="#f6ff00">email</td>
    </tr>
   <?php
   // fetch all rows dynamic 
   $query   = "select * from forms";
   $result  = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   while ($userSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
       echo "<tr>";

       echo "<td>{$userSet['created_time']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['specialist']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['full_name']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['city']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['country']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['date_of_birht']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['phone_number']}</td>";
       echo "<td>{$userSet['email']}</td>";

       echo "</tr>";
   }
   ?>
</table>
<?php include_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What did you try so far to implement such a feature?

Comment: im not expert in any programming languages thats why i asked the expert people here to help me

Comment: Even if we are experts, we do not write code for you. You have to try yourself and then if you have any issues/problems, you come to us and we help you. But we absolutely don't write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the data you can add an 'ORDER BY' clause in your SQL statement as follows:

```
select * from forms order by column
```

Comment: i need my employee to use in front end they dont have access to server or PhpMyAdmin

Comment: well if you place that query string in your code they wont need to have access to PHPMyAdmin

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it ? where i have to paste your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use jq datatable see the url it might help https://datatables.net/